# Adding an item to an editable menulist when it is typed in by the user

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

I am creating a menulist popup list dynamically. I the editable and open attributes to true. What I would like to be able to do is to be able to add a new menulist item when the user types in an item that is not already present. Is this possible? If so, how?

I am creating the list like so:

```
var ml = document.createElement("menulist");
ml.setAttribute("editable","true");
ml.setAttribute("open","true");
ml.setAttribute("oncommand","alert(this.value)");
var mp = document.createElement("menupopup");
var mi = document.createElement("menuitem");
mi.setAttribute("label","item1");
mi.setAttribute("value","1");
mp.appendChild(mi);
//add as many items as i feel
ml.appendChild(mp);
```

When the value is changed, the alert function is fired when the item is changed but when I type in anything, it is not fired. Basically, I want to eventually pass the value to a funcntion I call from here to add the item to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should seriously consider using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead of changing attributes like `oncommand`:

```
ml.addEventListener("command", function(event) {
 alert(this.value);
}, false);
```

If you want to be notified about changes in the text field then you should add an event listener to the text field:

```
ml.appendChild(mp);
ml.inputField.addEventListener("input", function(event)
{
  alert("Text field value changed");
}, false);
```

Note that this has to be done *after* the element is added to the document, before that the `inputField` property will not be defined (corresponding XBL binding didn't apply yet).

For reference: [menulist.inputField](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/menulist#p-menulist.inputField), [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input)